# Не сканируется строка

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть проблема в двух кейсах:

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введи первое число:");
        float a = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Введи второе число:");
        float b = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).");
        String operation = scanner.nextLine();
        switch (operation){
            case "+":
                System.out.println(a + b);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(a - b);
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println(a * b);
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println(a / b);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ты ввел неверную операцю");
        }
    }
}
```

а так же при:

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float first, second, result;
        String operation;
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write first number to the next line:");
        first = num.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Write first number to the next line:");
        second = num.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("What type of operation you want deal?");
        System.out.println("1. Write '+' if this addition.");
        System.out.println("2. Write '-' if this subtraction.");
        System.out.println("3. Write '*' if this multiplication.");
        System.out.println("4. Write '/' if this division.");
        System.out.println("Write what you want in next line:");
        operation = num.nextLine();
        if (operation == "+"){
            result = first + second;
            System.out.println(result);
        } else if (operation == "-") {
            result = first - second;
            System.out.println(result);
        } else if (operation == "*") {
            result = first * second;
            System.out.println(result);
        } else if (operation == "/") {
            result = first / second;
            System.out.println(result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You write other char. Please, try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Я ввожу числа, далее код должен меня попросить ввести операцию, в виде строки, но не просит, а сразу пишет else/default.

Comment: а зачем стринг импортировать??? `import java.lang.String;`

Comment: Операцию там же надо вводить, после чисел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тут проблема в выборе метода .
`nextLine()` -   считывает конец строки.
замените на метод `next()`

и во втором примере замените сравнения  `if (operation == "+")`
на `if (operation.equals("+"))`  и т.д.
т.к. через == сравнивают примитивы и адреса ссылок.

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое. Просто про сохранение в памяти "\n" ничего не гооврилось, как и про "next()", как и про equals (но, видимо, там switchCase нужны были). Почитал немного информации про это, все заработало! Добра тебе)

Comment: удачи в обучении

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введи первое число:");
    float a = scanner.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Введи второе число:");
    float b = scanner.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).");
    
    scanner.nextLine();
    
    
    String operation = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (operation){
        case "+":
            System.out.println(a + b);
            break;
        case "-":
            System.out.println(a - b);
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println(a * b);
            break;
        case "/":
            System.out.println(a / b);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Ты ввел неверную операцию");
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки в первом варианте:

- Использование `nextLine` после `nextFloat`:
  Если при вводе чисел используется `Enter` и они отделяются пустой строкой, `nextFloat` НЕ считывает символ `\n`, поэтому `nextLine` первым делом прочитает пустую строку, оставшуюся во входном потоке.
  Если же числа отделяются пробелами, аналогично `nextFloat` НЕ считывает пробелы, поэтому `nextLine` прочитает эти пробелы *вместе* с операцией, которая не сможет быть определена в операторе `switch` (можно сделать trim())

Для решения этих известных проблем следует унифицировать ввод:

1. Заменить `nextLine` на `next`, тогда ввод может выглядеть так:

```
Введи первое число:
1.25 Введи второе число:
8 Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).
* Операция: 1.25 * 8.0 = 10.0
```

2. Использовать `Float.parseFloat(scanner.nextLine())` для ввода чисел, при вводе перевод строки / `Enter` будут обязательны, кроме того, в качестве десятичного разделителя будет обрабатываться только точка.

---

Также недостатком может быть использование типа `float`, его точность недостаточна для простых операций, и могут возникать ошибки округления:

```
Введи первое число:
6,22
Введи второе число:
1,483
Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).
-
Операция: 6.22 - 1.483 = 4.7369995
```

При замене типа чисел на `double` точность несколько повысится, но гарантии корректного вывода нет:

```java
Введи первое число:
6,22
Введи второе число:
1,483
Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).
-
Операция: 6.22 - 1.483 = 4.737
```

```
Введи первое число:
6,22
Введи второе число:
3,181
Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /).
-
Операция: 6.22 - 3.181 = 3.0389999999999997
```

---

Рабочее решение:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Введи первое число: ");
double a = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine().replace(',', '.'));
System.out.print("Введи второе число: ");
double b = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine().replace(',', '.'));
System.out.print("Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /): ");
String operation = scanner.nextLine().trim(); // убрать ненужные пробелы
System.out.printf("Операция: %s %s %s = ", a, operation, b);
switch (operation) {
    case "+":
        System.out.println(a + b);
        break;
    case "-":
        System.out.println(a - b);
        break;
    case "*":
        System.out.println(a * b);
        break;
    case "/":
        System.out.println(a / b);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Неверная операция: " + operation + "!");
}
```

Возможный вывод:

```
Введи первое число: 6,22
Введи второе число: 1,117
Введи арифметическое действие (+, -, *, /): -
Операция: 6.22 - 1.117 = 5.103
```

---

В варианте с `if` операторами к существующим проблемам с вводом данных добавились некорректные сравнения строк при помощи оператора `==`, который подходит для сравнения `char`:

```
char operation = scanner.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
if ('+' == operation) {
...
} else if ('-' == operation) {
} // etc.
```

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое. Просто про сохранение в памяти "\n" ничего не гооврилось, как и про "next()", как и про equals (но, видимо, там switchCase нужны были). Почитал немного информации про это, все заработало! Добра тебе)